# Extract Z-values from multipoint feature in Pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, multipoint

I have a program that stores elevation data in a multipoint vector using QgsPoint.

```
    caps3 = mp_layer3.dataProvider().capabilities() #check layer capabilities
    if caps3 & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
      for loop 1:  (for loop over several lines)
        while loop 1: (while loop to save 3-D points on lines) 

        ... PROCESSING STUFF EXCLUDED FOR BREVITY ...

          mp.addGeometry(QgsPoint(pntxy.x(), pntxy.y(), zval[1], 0))
        
        xselevs.setGeometry(mp)
        xselevs.setAttributes([indx3])
        provider3.addFeature(xselevs)

      mp_layer3.updateExtents() 
      QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mp_layer3)
```

This all works great and I end up with a layer that has several multipoint features in it.  I can access x, y, z, and m in QGIS without any problem.  However, I want to be able to read back the layer in pyqgis, iterating over the features and reading the x, y, and z values.  I came up with the following:

```
    XSPntFeats = mp_layer3.getFeatures() #get all cross sections in new XS point file
    for XSPnts in XSPntFeats:  #loops through each multipoint contained in the shapefile
      for MPpart in XSPnts.geometry().asMultiPoint():   #loops through each part
        print("x-y-z: ", MPpart.x(), MPpart.y(), MPpart.z())
```

Works great for reading x and y, but alas, no z.  It throws an error since z is not a part of the asMultiPoint() function.  I can't find an iterator function that allows me to loop through each feature and read the points (including z) in them.  I have done a lot of searching and fiddling and I cannot find a way to iterate over the features to get z back (or m for that matter).

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for iterating through geometries, all fairly similar,a nd all of which will give you the same results - **for MultiPoints**. If you want to iterate through other geometry types, you will want to choose the right one for the job. For example, `vertices()` can be useful if you want to get the vertices of a MultiLineString or MultiPolygon without iterating through the parts.

**1. Use QgsGeometry.vertices()**

```
for f in vl.getFeatures():
  for v in f.geometry().vertices():
    print(v.x(), v.y(), v.z())
```

**2. Use QgsGeometry.constGet()**

```
for f in vl.getFeatures():
  for v in f.geometry().constGet():
    print(v.x(), v.y(), v.z())
```

**3. Use QgsGeometry.constParts()**

```
for f in vl.getFeatures():
  for v in f.geometry().constParts():
    print(v.x(), v.y(), v.z())
```

For the following raw data (ie a layer with two MultiPoints):

```
<QgsMultiPoint: MultiPointZ ((151.176021 -33.838767 100),(151.170861 -33.840853 101),(151.167229 -33.8419 102))>
<QgsMultiPoint: MultiPointZ ((151.140611 -33.807581 103),(151.156736 -33.792638 104))>
```

the output of each of the above is:

```
151.176021 -33.838767 100.0
151.170861 -33.840853 101.0
151.167229 -33.8419 102.0
151.140611 -33.807581 103.0
151.156736 -33.792638 104.0
```

To duplicate the data set up in QGIS, you can use the following PyQGIS code:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("MultiPointZ", "TempPoints", "memory")
mp1 = QgsMultiPoint()
mp2 = QgsMultiPoint()
mp1.addGeometry(QgsPoint(151.176021, -33.838767, 100))
mp1.addGeometry(QgsPoint(151.170861, -33.840853, 101))
mp1.addGeometry(QgsPoint(151.167229, -33.841900, 102))
mp2.addGeometry(QgsPoint(151.140611, -33.807581, 103))
mp2.addGeometry(QgsPoint(151.156736, -33.792638, 104))

vl.startEditing()
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(mp1)
vl.addFeature(feat)
feat.setGeometry(mp2)
vl.addFeature(feat)
vl.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your help with this, Tom.  I have been working on this problem for half a day and did not find anything online.  The constGet() function was something that I was exploring but was having trouble getting the data out of because I kept thinking that I had to refer to constGet().points() or something similar.  I didn't try your first and third answers, because the second was the one I was exploring at the time... Worked like a charm.  I am so grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I have three multipoints, first and second have three points each and third have only one.

How about:

```
for e, f in enumerate(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Draped")[0].getFeatures(),1): #For each feature
    print(f"Point: {e}")
    g = f.geometry() #Fetch its geometry
    for part in g.parts(): #For each part of the geometry
        print(round(part.z(),2)) #Each part is a QgsPoint Z, print the z value of it

#Point: 1
#684.04
#353.73
#470.05
#Point: 2
#603.41
#602.38
#552.46
#Point: 3
#311.85
```

Comment: I haven't tried this because I tried the constGet method described in another suggestion and it worked great for me.  I really appreciate the help, though, and it offers a lot of insight into the problem. Thanks so much... Dave